# Run PHP through Cron job

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I'm on Ubuntu and have a small backup script I've been trying to run. Unfortunately, it's not executing the backup. I've included the two PHP scripts here in case there's something I'm missing.

First, here's how how my crontab looks like

```
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/mybackup.php
```

The cron above supposed to call this script: `mybackup.php`

```
 <?php
include('myfunctions.php');

   theBackup();

?>
```

The main script is this. Although it works perfectly when I manually run it, but it does not run with cron.

```
<?php
/*
 * Script to back up the database
 * 
 *
*/

function getAllFiles($directory, $recursive = false) {
     $result = array();
     $handle =  opendir($directory);
     while ($datei = readdir($handle))
     {
          if (($datei != '.') && ($datei != '..'))
          {
               $file = $directory.$datei;
               if (is_dir($file)) {
                    if ($recursive) {
                         $result = array_merge($result, getAllFiles($file.'/'));
                    }
               } else {
                    $result[] = $file;
               }
          }
     }
     closedir($handle);
     return $result;
}

function getOldestTimestamp($directory, $recursive = true, $display ='file') {
     $allFiles = getAllFiles($directory, $recursive);
     $highestKnown = time();
     $highestFile = '';
     foreach ($allFiles as $val) {
          $currentValue = filemtime($val);
          $currentFile = $val;
          if ($currentValue < $highestKnown){
                $highestKnown = $currentValue;
                $highestFile = $currentFile;
          }
     }
    if($display=='file'){
        return $highestFile;
    } else {
        return $highestKnown;
    }
}


function theBackup(){

$sendfrom = "System Backup <admin@domain.com>";

$headers = 'Admin <admin@domain.com>' . "\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";

$filename = getOldestTimestamp('./app/db/',true,'file');
$filename = str_replace("./app/db/", "", $filename );

$backupfile = '/var/www/app/db/'.$filename;
$handle  = fopen($backupfile, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$backupfile); 

$dbhost  = "localhost";  
$dbuser  = "user";
$dbpass  = "password";
$dbname  = "db";

if(system("mysqldump -h $dbhost -u $dbuser  -p$dbpass  $dbname  > $backupfile") == false){
    mail('email@yahoo.com','My Backup','Back Up successfully completed',$headers );

  }else {
    mail('email@yahoo.com','My Backup','Back Up did NOT complete successfully please check the file/folder 

permission',$headers );

   }   
 }
?>
```

Is there anything I'm missing from the code above? Like I said, when I run mybackup.php from the browser, it works perfectly, but not through cron.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with including files inside your cron's PHP.  Have you tried copying and pasting the included code into your file just to see if that is, indeed, the issue?

Comment: What's the error into the phpcli log?

Comment: I haven't checked the phpcli log. Will check and report back later.

Answer (score 1):

You're using absolute path to run the php in the cron job

```
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/mybackup.php
```

And the include URL is relative

```
include('myfunctions.php');
```

Try using absolute URL to the include too.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried making it absolute, but it didn't make any difference :(

Comment: I think the URL in line: `$filename = getOldestTimestamp('./app/db/',true,'file');` on your function `theBackup()` should be absolute too

Comment: Thanks again. I will try that and see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need the full path to your include, where you say:

```
include('myfunctions.php');
```

should be like

```
include('/var/www/myfunctions.php');
```

or wherever that is.
Also check you logs to see what error messages you are getting